# ECS - communication between tasks

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy 2 containers on 2 different tasks (1 container per task), one is my frontend and the other is my backend server. I am trying to figure out how to configure the communication between them.

I saw that a load balancer in a service is a good option. However, should I configure load balancer for my front end server and another one for my backend? Meaning each time I have public-facing services and private services I need 2 load balancers?

I would like to only expose my front-end to the public internet and my backend will remain private (although I make API requests to the outside world - probably need to configure outbound route too?).

I would highly appreciate any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need a private LB for that. It is an option you can use but ECS has since introduced the concept of [Service Discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) for back-end services. The idea is that your front end is exposed to your users via a standard LB (e.g. ALB) but services that are being called by the front end and that run behind the scene can be addressed using this service discovery mechanism (based on Route53/CloudMap).

You can see an example of this concept [here](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/tree/master/deployments/platformdeployment/AWS/ECS). [This](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/tree/master/deployments/platformdeployment/AWS/ECS/cfn) CFN template gives you the details re how you can build this layout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to deploy my app without any extra payments and I saw that LB/Service Discovery/NAT all cost money. Is there a way to configure tasks/EC2s to communicate with each other without using the above mentioned solutions?

Comment: We introduced Service Discovery to lower the charge of using a LB but I can't think of a way to bring it to 0. The only thing I can think of is that if you consolidate both the front end and back end containers in a single task you can refer to the back end service with `localhost` and thus you would not need Service Discovery (but this would be a solid anti-pattern and I would advise against it).

Comment: Yeah I thought about it too but figured out that this is not a good option to have them both on same instance. I will check the SD option. Thank you very much!