# AWS ECS architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, api-gateway

I have a react frontend and flask backend and I would like to deploy them with ECS. I want to make the react app public facing and the flask server to be hidden and not accessible from the outside world.

From what I read, the approach should be as follows:

1. create a public and private subnets with NAT gateway on the public subnet for the flask server.
2. deploy the react app in the public sub and the server on the private sub.

Now here is where I get confused:

1. How can I expose the react app to the outside world? should I use Internet gateway or ELB/ALB? what are the differences?
2. How do I make the react app talk to the server when the server only have private IP? Service discovery? And if so, how should I inject the server's service name to the react app using docker?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can I expose the react app to the outside world? should I use Internet gateway or ELB/ALB? what are the differences?

If react frontend is static website, then probably would be best to use **S3 + CloudFront** for hosting it. But if you want to use ECS, then yes, using internet facing load balancer is how it is usually done.

ELB is **first generation** of load balancers. These days you should use ALB with is **second generation** balancer which provide many more features then ELB, e.g. redirection from http to https.

Internet gateway is for your VPC, its only needed if you use custom destined VPC. If you use **default VPC**, then you don't have to worry about it.

> 2. How do I make the react app talk to the server when the server only have private IP? Service discovery? And if so, how should I inject the server's service name to the react app using docker?

You can't use private IP nor service discovery. Your frontend will execute in your clients browser so it has to **use internet** to talk with your backend. This means you need to expose your Flask API using public IP, not private.

This again could be done using public ALB. You could use the **same ALB** as for the front-end. So you would have the following setup:

```
                                   |---> Target Group 1 ---> ECS Services for React frontend (private subnet)
Client ---> ALB (public subnet) ---|
                                   |---> Target Group 2 ---> ECS Service for Flask (private subnet)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I don't want my flask server to be accessible by users from the outside, so how can I prevent it? Additionally, I created a new VPC with private and public subnets

Comment: In the thread I was told service discovery is an option. This is not the case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975605/ecs-communication-between-tasks

Comment: @GiladDahan You can't prevent it. Your flask must be exposed to the internet. At best you can use ALB (as I wrote in the answer), APi gateway or lambda as a proxy between internet and your flask service. Service discovery is for private IPs, you need public.

Comment: I am looking at the docs and from what I read here it looks like it is possible what I am trying to achieve. It says: "We recommend this scenario if you want to run a public-facing web application, while maintaining back-end servers that aren't publicly accessible" -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html am I missing something?

Comment: @GiladDahan Yes, and my answer falls with this link. In this case, ALB is in public subnet and your ECS service with flask is in private subnet. I can update the answer to make it clear.

Comment: So just to make sure, the flask server does not require public IP? And the communication between the react app and flask still need to go through LB ?

Comment: @GiladDahan Yes, because your frontend executes on the client side, in a browser. You have to use internet to connect from it to your flask, and this is where ALB is  used.

Comment: @Marcin I am a little bit confused by your diagram, as the client accesses `http://www.example.com`, which the ALB forwards to **a** target group. Can you let me know if the following logic makes sense? Let's say I set up the following target listeners: `HTTP 80 → frontend` & `HTTP 5000 → backend`.  So when I access `http://www.example.com`, since http is port **80** it uses the **frontend** target (and service). However, if the frontend makes a request to `http://www.example.com:5000/<api_route>`, the ALB will forward it to the **backend** target (due to port **5000**)?

Comment: @lbragile Please make new question specific to your issue.

Comment: @Marcin asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167398/aws-ecs-frontend-backend-communication), thanks in advance!