# AWS ECS Frontend & Backend Communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Based on [AWS ECS architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344027/aws-ecs-architecture)

@Marcin purposed an interesting idea, but I cannot wrap my head around how the ALB knows which target group to forward to, as my attempts with 2 listeners (HTTP 80 → Frontend & HTTP 5000 → Backend) did not work.

Let's say I have the following (as @Marcin purposed)

```
                                   |---> Target Group 1 ---> ECS Services for Frontend (private subnet)
Client ---> ALB (public subnet) ---|
                                   |---> Target Group 2 ---> ECS Service for Backend (private subnet)
```

Assume:

- the ALB is accessible via `http://www.example.com` and listens on:
- HTTP **80** → forward to target Group 1
- HTTP **5000** → forward to target Group 2
- frontend container is exposed on port `3000`
- backend container is exposed on port `5000`
- target group 1 maps to `HTTP 3000`
- target group 2 maps to `HTTP 5000`

Reasoning for the above setup was that if client wants a frontend resource, the access `http://www.example.com` (port 80), but if the frontend makes an API request to the backend, it does so via `http://www.example.com:5000/<end_point>` (note the **:5000**).

However, this hangs due to timeout

```
POST http://www.example.com:5000/check net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I can see that both target groups pass their respective health-checks in AWS console

Did I get something wrong with the above reasoning, or is this a setup issue?

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` often suggests incorrect security groups or network ACLs.

Comment: Yes, this indeed was the issue, I had the load balancer security group as ipv4/6 anywhere to **HTTP 80** only. As soon as I added the ipv4/6 to **CUSTOM TCP 5000** I started getting backend responses - thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I will make the answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was with luck of a rule in **ALB's security group** to allow port 5000. Thus, the solution was to add the needed rule.

Comment: I have a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224321/aws-load-balancer-register-de-register-cycle-only-on-backend-service

Would greatly appreciate any feedback you may have