# Application Load Balancer Target Group Register/Deregister Infinite Loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

### Setup

##### Security Groups

- ALB (inbound rules)

  - `HTTPS:443 from 0.0.0.0/0 & ::/0`
  - `HTTP:80 from 0.0.0.0/0 & ::/0`
- Cluster (inbound rules)

  - All traffic from ALB security group

#### Cluster

- instance is t2.micro (only running 1 instance in subnets `us-east-1<a,b,c>` under default VPC with public IP enabled)
- client → `0.375 vCPU/0.25 GB, 1 task, bridge network, 0:3000 (host:container)`
- server → `0.25 vCPU/0.25 GB, 2 tasks, bridge network, 0:5000 (host:container)`

#### ALB

- availability zones: `us-east-1<a,b,c>`, same default VPC
- listeners:

  - `HTTP:80 → redirect to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}`
  - `HTTPS:443 (/) → forward to client target group`
  - `HTTPS:443 (/api) → forward to server target group`

#### Target Groups

- client → HTTP:3000 with default health check of `HTTP, /, Traffic Port, 5 healthy, 2 unhealthy, 5s timeout, 30s interval, 200 OK`
- server → HTTP:5000 with health check of `HTTP, /api/health, Traffic Port, 5 healthy, 2 unhealthy, 5s timeout, 30s interval, 200 OK`

Both docker images for client and server work properly locally & the client service seems to work well in AWS ECS. However, the server service keeps cycling between registering and de-registering (draining) the container instances seemingly **without** even becoming unhealthy

Here is what I see in the service `Deployments and events` tab:

```
5/12/2022, 8:43:04 PM   service server registered 2 targets in target-group <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:54 PM   service server has started 2 tasks: task <...> task <...>.  <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:51 PM   service server deregistered 1 targets in target-group <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:51 PM   service server has begun draining connections on 1 tasks.   <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:51 PM   service server deregistered 1 targets in target-group <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:17 PM   service server registered 2 targets in target-group <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:07 PM   service server has started 2 tasks: task <...> task <...>.  <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:04 PM   service server deregistered 1 targets in target-group <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:04 PM   service server has begun draining connections on 1 tasks.   <...>
5/12/2022, 8:42:04 PM   service server deregistered 1 targets in target-group <...>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, would greatly appreciate any debugging tips & tricks for AWS

Comment: What are the security groups used?

Comment: I mentioned them in the setup section. The only piece I overlooked was the RDS instance SG which accepts ALB SG on 5432 (see answer below), everything works now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling AWS CloudWatch logs in my task definition's container specs, I was able to see that the issue was actually with an AWS RDS instance.

The RDS instances' SG was accepting traffic from an old cluster SG (which no longer exists), so that clears up why a health check wasn't being performed and the registered instances were draining immediately.